ssh/scp stop working when a large quantity of data has been copied
From time to time I am copying data from my laptop Apple Air to a linux host.
If the sums of the sizes of the files copied is above a number of GB (not clear what the limit is) I get a error (most of files are from few MB to 300 MB each):
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
scp: Connection closed

After this happens, all the secure connections are killed.
I try reconnecting using scp and/or ssh but I always fail with a client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe error.
In all cases I have a prompt, I enter my password and my 2FA.
Usually after some minutes or many minutes the situation clears itself.
using of many '-v' flags in ssh and scp does not let me be the wiser.
uname -a:
Linux  3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 7 15:41:52 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ssh -V:
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

on another host
Linux 5.15.0-122-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 29 13:45:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

I do not have SysAdmin privileges on all hosts.
On my laptop I have sonoma 14.6.1 but the error I report was seen also on previous MacOs.
let me know if you have any idea.
thank you

Do all connections die at once if you e.g. have an interactive SSH session open at the same time while transferring files? Do you use SSH connection multiplexing (the ControlPath, ControlMaster settings in .ssh/config)?

yes all interactive ssh die. not https or zoom or other secure connections ('possibly' because they were not created via sshd).
BTW nor use of ControlPath, ControlMaster in ssh config files (at least that I have seen)
